# How to do Data profile to a table using pandas_profiling

Tags: python, pandas-profiling

When I'm trying to do data profiling one sql server table by using pandas_profiling throwing an error like

An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

```
    This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
    child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
    in the main module:

        if __name__ == '__main__':
            freeze_support()
            ...

    The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
    is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

This is the code which I'm using to run,I couldn't figure out how to resolve this issue.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_profiling


df=pd.DataFrame(read)
profile=pandas_profiling.ProfileReport(df)

enter code here
```

I expect to see a profiling result of a given table:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try using multiprocessing.freeze_support() as below:

```
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas_profiling


def test_profile():
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        np.random.rand(100, 5),
        columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
    )

    profile = pandas_profiling.ProfileReport(df)
    profile.to_file(outputfile="output.html")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    test_profile()
```